# Returning an Object with a guid and string from a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method which i pass in a file name and file path in which i will be saving to. 
The file is put in a for loop so that i save each page as a separate file. At the same time each page will contain a barcode that i am reading off. I want to store each barcode and file path in a list in which i return so i can use in a different method.

```
public __________ InputFile(string fileName, string filePath)
{
     for(int page = 1; page <= fileName.PageCount; page++)
     {
          read barcode
          save page as new file
     }
     return ___________;
}
```

I already have what i need to read and save the file i just want to know how do i set this up to return an object of the barcode and the path?

Comment: `I want to store each barcode and file path in a list` Tuple, KeyValuePair, Dictionary, Your own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer would be to write your own class that stores the value and return a List of that type. If you don't want to write your own class, then you can look into using the `System.Tuple<T,U>` type.

**EDIT:**

Here's what the class might look like (class and property names can be changed to anything you'd like).

```
public class Result
{
  public Guid Barcode {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

In your method, create a new instance of `List<Result>`, and for each iteration of the loop, create a new instance of `Result` and add it to the list, then return the list.

Comment: If i wanted to write my own class how would that look? create a class for each of the two?

Comment: I edited my answer to show what the class might look like and gave a more detailed explanation of how to return the values.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to create a class explicit to store these values and return an instance of your class.

```
public class MyResult
{
    public Guid Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public MyResult InputFile(string fileName, string filePath) { ... }
```

Alternatively you could use a `Tuple`, then you would return `Tuple<Guid, string>` and create it with `Tuple.Create(guid, path)`. You access the values with the properties `Item1` and `Item2`. Due to this naming you really should use the first approach, as it is more explicit.

Comment: then my return within the method would be like `return MyResult`?

Comment: You would instantiate an instance of your class and initialize the properties: `new MyResult { BarCode = .., Path = .. }`. These are the absolute minimum basics of C#, perhaps you should grab a book and read it first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could return an

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<Barcode, string>>
```

if you didn't want to have another class.

Answer (score 0):

Either create your own object with 2 properties or use a Tuple

```
Tuple<GUID, string> tuple = new Tuple<GUID, string>();
```